# Scanner class methods

Tags: java, methods

Ok, so I'm a complete beginner, and if this is a really dumb question for you, I'm sorry.

So I started using the Scanner class, and something seems strange to me.

For example, these lines of code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Write string: ");

if(scan.hasNextInt()){

    int x = scan.nextInt();
}
else
    System.out.println("Only integers allowed");
```

How does it know whether the user typed an integer or not, if I'm only getting the input inside the 'if' condition?

Comment: @Okx, oh it works just fine.

Comment: Since every question you create starts with "Java" in the title: [Stop doing that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 2):

According to Java documentation:

hasNextInt() "returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value." So this method looks at the input, and if the next thing in it is an integer, it returns true. The scanner has not yet "read" the input by putting it into a variable.

Comment: But what does radix mean? The number of characters to be read? Or the total number of characters on the line that are ints?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to look at the actual implementation of `hasNextInt`, then you can see how it knows:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
 * interpreted as an int value in the specified radix using the
 * {@link #nextInt} method. The scanner does not advance past any input.
 *
 * @param radix the radix used to interpret the token as an int value
 * @return true if and only if this scanner's next token is a valid
 *         int value
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this scanner is closed
 */
public boolean hasNextInt(int radix) {
    setRadix(radix);
    boolean result = hasNext(integerPattern());
    if (result) { // Cache it
        try {
            String s = (matcher.group(SIMPLE_GROUP_INDEX) == null) ?
                processIntegerToken(hasNextResult) :
                hasNextResult;
            typeCache = Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Note**: `hasNextInt()` just calls `hasNextInt(int radix)`, where `defaultRadix = 10`

```
public boolean hasNextInt() {
    return hasNextInt(defaultRadix);
}
```